Closing Off Joist Cavity in New Basement Room
I'm currently planning a project to build out a wall for a half bath in a basement and have been struggling to find some solutions that would close off the joist spacing on the outside of the basement wall. The ceiling is and will remain unfinished outside of the bathroom. This is a picture that I found browsing for a solution that effectively captures what the framing situation will look like. I'm looking to block it off primarily due to sounds easily propagating over the wall without something to block it, and I wasn't sure just throwing insulation over it would be appropriate or even against code.
With relevance to code, I'm in Michigan. Are there any good ways to do this? I can only imagine wood blocking as a solution (i.e., using the same joist size wood as blocking above the wall), but I'm unaware of any code implications with that route. Any thoughts or suggestions would be welcome.
I'm also aware of separate code considerations outside the scope of this post (electrical, ventilation, etc.) but wanted to focus on the framing aspect here.

More blocking should be okay.  Most codes require the minimums to be done, but don't stop going above.  Your local building department will be the best to answer local code requirements.
